# PC-Lint, std::map and error 613 (possible use of null ptr)

Tags: c++, nullptr, pc-lint

I tried to use PC-Lint with an option +fnr. It makes lint suspect that  all pointer-like returns from functions could be nullptr.

But for some functions I know they won't return nullptr in any case. To tell PC-Lint that it can ignore nullptr check for them I can use

```
-sem(func, @p != 0)
```

But there is another problem: PC-Lint cannot correctly check situation when standard containers return iterators.

```
// using +fnr in .lnt file
//lint -sem(f1, @p != 0)
//lint -sem(std::map::find, @p != 0)
#include<map>

int* f1();

int main()
{
    int* p1 = f1();
    *p1 = 2;            // -sem worked

    std::map<int, int> m;
    std::map<int, int>::iterator it = m.find(1);
    if (it != m.end())
        it->second = 12;// even -sem doesn't work
}
```

It generates

```
C:\lint_test\f3.cpp(18): Issue 613: (Warning -- Possible use of null pointer 'unknown-name' in left argument to operator '->' [Reference: file C:\lint_test\f3.cpp: line 18])
```

If PC-Lint is not smart enough to see that I check the iterator before using I would like at least turn off this check for std::map::find. But I can't, -sem doesn't work

Does anyone know how to address this problem?

Comment: Yes, map::find does return an object. And I was surprised that lint generated me that error. But I need to do something about it.